# Is boost supportable with metro style app?

Tags: boost, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I have  a desktop application which use boost library **1.49**(that was built on **msvc : 11**).I want to port my desktop app to metro style.Can i use this boost library with my Metro App.
Specifically my question is that if boost uses any API that is restricted for **WinRT**?

Comment: That largely depends on which boost components you use. Everything that doesn't have to deal with system specifics should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [list of COM/Win32 APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx) that are available to a Metro style app.  If the component keeps to those APIs, it will be fine for a Metro style app.